# Boxplots in a matrix with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Need to obtain 24 boxplots in two columns (12 per row) and print them into a postscript file.

**This code throws an error**

```
def do(self, ...):
    axarray = plt.subplots(12, 3, figsize=(11.69,8.27))
    for i in range(2):
        for month in range(12):
            monthBoxplot = [    [ 2, 2, 2 ], 
                                [ 2, 2, 2 ] ]
            axarray[i, m].boxplot(monthBoxplot)
    ax.imshow(axarray, aspect='normal')
    plt.savefig("/asdasd"+str(year)+".ps")
```

**The error**

> ```
> axarray[i,m].boxplot(boxplotMensual)
> ```
>
> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple

**It means that `[i,m]` is a tuple...right? What should i do?**
Thanks

Comment: This code throws a NameError : name 'm' is not defined

Comment: You copied the first line of my code wrong, you missed the f in the assignment

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sorry, didn't know that f was being used.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain the error you obtained. Also, it would be useful to edit your question to include the (general) python tag

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
f, axarray = plt.subplots(12, 3, figsize=figsize)
for i in range(2):
    for month in range(12):
        axarray[i, month].boxplot(data)
```

should do.

Lots of example for subplots are available [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html).

Edit : actually f is not used, you can replace f with _ in the first line. But if you don't put `f`, `axarray` is not assigned the correct object. To simplify, can you see the difference between `a1, a2 = 3, 4` and `a2 = 3, 4`? In the second case, a2 is a tuple, and if you do `a2[0, 0]` (i.e. `axarray[i, m]` in your code, when axarray is a tuple), you get an error because you cannot index tuples with a tuple.